# PROMPT_DIRTRIM not working

Tags: bash, terminal, prompt, bashrc

I have the following in my `.bash_profile`:

```
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3
export PS1='$ \u in \w: '
```

However, when I navigate deep within a directory, the path doesn't shorten. This is what the prompt shows:

```
$ myname in ~/Desktop/level3/level4/level5:
```

I've tried restarting iTerm, but it didn't help. When I run `bash --version`, I get the following output:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT** Going even deeper:

```
$ myname in ~/Desktop/level3/level4/level5/level6/level7/level8/level9:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go a few levels deeper then it'll start truncating

```
$ sweh in ~: cd D1
$ sweh in ~/D1: cd D2
$ sweh in ~/D1/D2: cd D3
$ sweh in ~/D1/D2/D3: cd D4
$ sweh in ~/D1/D2/D3/D4: cd D5
$ sweh in ~/.../D3/D4/D5: cd D6
$ sweh in ~/.../D4/D5/D6:
```

Outside of $HOME it *appears* to truncates earlier:

```
$ sweh in ~: cd /usr/local/share/locale/
$ sweh in .../local/share/locale:
```

You can see it wants to keep 3 levels of directory in both cases, but inside $HOME it prefixes with ~/ and it is smart enough to know that 4 directories vs 3 directories and `...` doesn't really matter in that case.

The native version of `bash` that comes with MacOS isn't new enough to understand this.  If you have installed a newer version (eg via `brew` or from source) then you need to make sure you have changed your user shell via the `chsh` command so that your running `bash` window uses the new version of `bash` and not the old built in one.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working :/. Check out my updated post.

Comment: Try `export PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3` in the profile just in case it's a subshell issue...

Comment: Hmm, I tried that as well and it isn't working. I'm not sure what the issue is here because the exact same thing seems to work when I do it on my other laptop. This is a new laptop and I don't know if I did something that could have messed it up. I installed bash through Homebrew in order to upgrade it to version 4. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Very possibly in issue with that version of `bash`, yes.  Does the MacOS default `/bin/bash` work?

Comment: When I do `/bin/bash --version` I see that it says version `3.2.57`. I'm guessing this is the reason it isn't working because it needs a version of 4.0 to use `PROMPT_DIRTRIM`?

Comment: Likely, yeah.  The manpage on my Mac doesn't reference DIRTRIM under the `\w` section, but on my Linux machine it does.

Comment: Awesome, I was able to get it fixed by following the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/samnang/1759336). I had stopped after doing `brew install bash`, but there were a couple of other things you had to do after that. Thanks for the help, do you want to modify your answer a bit based on this so that I can accept it?

Comment: Ah, I guess the `chsh` so that you use the new shell and not the built-in one.  Answer updated :-)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

Install Bash 4 using homebrew

`brew install bash`

Add the new shell to the list of legit shells

`sudo bash -c "echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /private/etc/shells"`

Change the shell for the user

`chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`

Restart terminal.app (new window works too)

`exec bash`

Shout out to the [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/samnang/1759336) author that provided the info!